# if file_exists not working with wp_enqueue_style

Tags: php, css, wp-enqueue-script

Inside a function I'm doing something like this:

```
$optional_css_exists = get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/optional.css";
  if ( file_exists($optional_css_exists) ) {
      wp_enqueue_style('options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/optional.css', 'style');
  }
```

But for some reason it's not being enqueued. When I echo out $optional_css_exists, I get the correct path of the file.

If I remove the if statement, the file is enqueued.

Why isn't the file being enqueued when it exists and the path is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL path can't be passed to `file_exists`

[PHP: file_exists - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Use `get_template_directory()` or `get_stylesheet_directory()` instead:

```
if(file_exists(get_template_directory()./path/file.css'))
```

as that returns server path

Comment: Thank you! I used get_template_directory() instead and now it works.

Comment: Oops. Yes. `template`, not `sylesheet`. Good catch.